# Reordering a conditionally convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}=\ln(2),$$
and I want to reorder it to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8n-3}{2n(4n-3)(4n-1)}.$$
If we write the terms of the first series we get $1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{6}+...$,
if we group each set of three successive terms we get $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{13}{140}+\frac{7}{198}+...$

> 1 How do I show that this is equal to the second series?
>   2 How do I show that the second series cannot have the values $\ln(2)$?

I was thinking about using partial fractions for the first one, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They are not Equal**

Using [Partial Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8n-3}{2n(4n-3)(4n-1)}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4n-3}+\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{2n}\right)\tag{1}
$$
The first series is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4n-3}+\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{4n}-\frac1{4n-2}\right)\tag{2}
$$
The difference is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4n-2}-\frac1{4n}\right)
=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\tag{3}
$$
Thus, it seems that $(1)$ is equal to $\frac32$ of $(2)$.

---

**Reordering the Series**

The [Riemann Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) says that we can reorder the terms of any conditionally convergent series so that they sum to any real number we wish. That is, we can reorder the terms of $(2)$ to get $(1)$.

That is, all the terms in $(2)$ appear in $(1)$, but the even terms are just delayed, the higher indexed terms are delayed further.

Comment: How do you find the second identity?

Comment: Simply write the terms four at a time. The the terms with even denominators have a negative sign and those with odd denominators have a positive sign.

Comment: What do you mean by "four at a time"?

Comment: The left side is $\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14 +\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18+\dots$ the right side is $\left(\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14\right) +\left(\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18\right)+\dots$

Comment: Ok thanks! But what if you write them three at a time?

Comment: As I have tried to make clearer in the last line, the series in $(1)$ is simply a reordering of that in $(2)$. The terms in $(1)$ are taken "three at a time"